# Mapping Composite keys in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am new to Fluent NHibernate and have been unable to figure out how to map composite keys.

How can I do this? What approach do I need to take?

Comment: Can find more detailed example here: https://web.archive.org/web/20111021204316/http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/01/16/using-fluentnhibernate-to-map-composite-keys-for-a-table.aspx

Answer (score 53):

There's a `CompositeId` method.

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
      CompositeId()
      .KeyProperty(x => x.Something)
      .KeyReference(x => x.SomethingElse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that in new versions of NHibernate UseCompositeId is replaced with CompositeId, and WithKeyProperty is just KeyProperty

Comment: @Rob Walker : Also WithReferenceProperty has become KeyReference

Comment: What's the difference in KeyProperty and KeyReference in this case?

Comment: The examples i'm seeing suggest that KeyProperty would be the "ID" and KeyReference would be the Entity. So use KeyProperty for "CustomerID", use KeyReference for "Customer" instance

Answer (score 5):

if this is your first class

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
    UseCompositeId()
      .WithKeyProperty(x => x.Something)
      .WithReferenceProperty(x => x.SomethingElse);
  }
}
```

here is the second with a reference on Entity

```
public class SecondEntityMap : ClassMap<SecondEntity>
    {
      public SecondEntityMap()
      {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        ....

        References<Entity>(x => x.EntityProperty)
          .WithColumns("Something", "SomethingElse")
          .LazyLoad()
          .Cascade.None()
          .NotFound.Ignore()
          .FetchType.Join();

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to note is that you must override the Equals and GetHashCode methods for an entity using a CompositeId. Given the accepted answers mapping file, your entity would look like this.

```
public class Entity
{
   public virtual int Something {get; set;}
   public virtual AnotherEntity SomethingElse {get; set;}


   public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Entity;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.SomethingElse == SomethingElse && other.Something == Something;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (SomethingElse.GetHashCode()*397) ^ Something;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a need for entities with composite identifiers, entities that map to tables which have composite primary keys, composed of many columns. The columns that make up this primary key are usually foreign keys to another tables.

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{      
   public UserMap()
   {
        Table("User");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");

        CompositeId()
          .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ID")
          .KeyReference(x => x.User, "USER_ID");

        Map(x => x.Name).Column("NAME");               

        References(x => x.Company).Column("COMPANY_ID").ForeignKey("ID");
    }
}
```

For more reference : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/419780/NHibernate-mappings-for-Composite-Keys-with-associ

Comment: "The columns that make up this primary key are usually foreign keys to another tables."
No, not usually. If anything, they help identify an entity uniquely where one column fails to do so on its own.